# How to find xPub from wallet address

Tags: transactions, address, xpub

I'm trying to find a master public key (I believe this is the xPub) of an electrum wallet I no longer have access to. This is ok, I've moved all BTC from there. The thing is, I need the public key to keep track of my transactions.

Given the single wallet address I can find all the transactions on blockchain.com, but I'm not able to understand where some of the transactions sent BTC to. Is this possible?

For example, this addresses latest transaction: https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/3DnByQ6HVhcFLj452uxWDZ7ZefSxQ6SsWE
states that 0.01403834 was sent somewhere, but it then lists 100's of addresses.

Which one of these was the 0.01403834 sent to?

**Recap**

To recap, I need a way to know either

1. the xPub key from a single wallet address OR
2. be able to read all transactions on an address on something like blockchain.com - That said this doesn't cover all the transactions on that wallet, it only covers transactions at that single address correct? So this leads me to believe I still need the xPub.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the xpub won't help you understand that transaction

An address used 46699 times receiving hundreds of millions of dollars is probably one that belongs to an exchange.

Addresses that start with 3 are P2SH. The H means hash. You can't find the xPub key from a hash.

Comment: Even if you somehow knew the public key used in the comstruction of an address, that would still not permit you to find the xpub it was generated by.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to recover the wallet in order to get the xPub.

An xPub is what derives all the receive addresses, the process cannot be reversed.